# JavaScript ／ constructorプロパティは、コンストラクタ関数にも、コンストラクタ関数.prototypeにも存在する？

Tags: javascript

・constructorプロパティは、コンストラクタ関数にも、コンストラクタ関数.prototypeにも、存在するのでしょうか？
・それとも、プロトタイプチューンを辿って単にそう見えるだけ？

下記は何が違うのでしょうか？
・「Hoge.constructor」「Hoge.prototype.constructor」に何らかのオブジェクトは存在する？
・それぞれの役割は？
・どういうタイミングで作成される？

---

function Hoge() {};

1
console.log(Hoge);

2
console.log(Hoge.prototype.constructor);

3
console.log(Hoge.constructor.prototype);

4
console.log(Hoge.prototype.constructor.prototype);

---

3
・Hoge.constructor.prototypeに実体はあるでしょうか？
・それとも、プロトタイプチューンを辿って取得した結果を表示しているだけ？

4
・ここに継承したオブジェクトが保存される？

---

理解できないので質問追記します。
・下記ページに以下の記載があるのですが、この仕様はどこで確認できるでしょうか？

> 継承されたオブジェクトはconstructor.prototypeに格納される
>   http://qiita.com/maccotsan/items/45b348d4eb52f473b0e3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

関数が定義されると、関数オブジェクトのprototypeプロパティに、constructorプロパティが自分自身のオブジェクトが設定されます。
つまりHoge.prototype.constructor→Hogeです。それ以外は特別なことはなく、
Hoge.constructorはプロトタイプチェーンをさかのぼって
Hoge.__proto__.constructor→Function.prototype.constructor→Functionです。